# How to set Max Pool Size of SqlConnection string in c# on asmx web service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, web-services

I have a physical server with SQL Server 2008 installed on it. Recently `sqlservr.exe` consumes excessive CPU and RAM.

When I investigated the reasons for this, I learned that it was due to the links opened and that the pool setting was enabled.

All my connections to my database are in a single asmx file, so there is no other connection string.

Here is my connection string

```
 Server=server;Database=dbxxx;User Id=sas;Password=sssxxxx;Max Pool Size=1000;
```

The program that connects to this web service uses approximately 3 to 4 thousand users per day. The web service daily runs approximately 20 thousand SQL queries per day.

The presenter has 8 gb of RAM and he gets to use 7 gb ram right in the morning with no decrease in usage from 1.7 gb in the morning, or even ever increasing.

How should max pool be set up because you have a single web service connection? Do I do the right thing or is there something extreme?

Comment: In determining max pool size we should consider what will be the average concurrent transactions. 20.000 queries not too much in daily basis, so you should firstly decrease max pool size to something between 100-200. In addition, be careful not to left connect open, you can use connection creation with `using` statement.

Comment: I get an error when i set max pool size 200 but there are not any error when i set to 1000

Comment: Can you share the error details, is it something like `Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool`?

Comment: @balayoglu True.I get "Timeout expired" error

Comment: It is possible that you have a bug in your code, you leave open connection I guess. You can use the using keyword when creating sql connection like:  `using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("connection_string")) {
                con.Open();
                // Do the DML things here
            }`